# Why does the output from dea() does not match with the (visual) results from dea.plot() (Benchmarking package in R)?

Tags: r, benchmarking

I am trying to visualize my results from a data envelopment analysis (DEA). I use the "Benchmarking" library for this purpose (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Benchmarking/Benchmarking.pdf). 
Oddly, my results from the dea() function do not match with the visual results from the dea.plot() function.

I use two input and two output variables for my model and a variable return to scale (VRS) assumption.

```
Y = data_set[,c('input1', 'input2')]

X = data_set[,c('output1', 'output2')]
```

My model

```
dea_model = dea(X,Y, RTS = "vrs")
```

yields 18 efficient decision making units (DMUs) with efficiency = 1 (from a total of 31 DMUs). Here you got my output:

1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.4166667
 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3000000 0.2500000 0.2500000

Now, when I call the dea.plot() function to visualize my results

```
dea.plot(X, Y, RTS = "vrs")
```

there are only 3 points on the efficiency frontier, instead of 18.

What is the problem here? Is the dea.plot() function not able to aggregate both input and output dimensions? The documentation says:

"The good illustrated on the first axis. If there are more than 1 input then inputs are just summed or, if wx is present, a weighted sum of inputs is used."

Therefore, I assumed that the dea.plot() function does take the different inputs and outputs into account.

Comment: Hi @Hergen. Could you please provide some piece of data to facilitate the reproduction of your example?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is also a warning saying:

"If you use this facility to plot multi input and multi output then **the plot may deceive you**, as fully multi efficient firms are not necessarely placed on the two-dimensional frontier."

I believe this is your case.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you are operating with multiple inputs or outputs or both, hence two-dimensional space will not suffice to represent your data. In order to be able to plot it, you should decrease the dimension of your data. The function you refer to or its extension that includes the frontier has an argument that helps you aggregate your data `dea.plot.frontier(X,Y, RTS = "vrs", wx=wx)` where `wx` should be a vector or matrix that matches your dimension and represents the weights you want to put on each variable for the aggregation.